# Could the US extradite the Russian Hackers?

Tags: united-states, extradition, russia

Many people get *extradited for breaking a country's laws by hacking against that country.* This is how International Cyberattackers get brung to justice, But what if one Jurisdiction Government personnel **commits a crime against one country** but was working for a foreign government, does extradition apply to this? Is there forced extradition? **Could the US extradite the Russian Hackers who started the cyber attack against the US private sector and US government agencies and departments?**

Comment: If we are talking about "Russian hackers in Russia", then the USA government does not "extradite them". It might **demand the extradition** to the Russian government, which would be the one to decide if it complies or not. Even if there was a mechanism for that (i.e. extradition treaty) and the Russian government was willing, the USA government would have to identify them and provide evidence of their activities.

Comment: Russia doesn't have an extradition treaty with the US, what would compel them to obey an extradition order? Didn't work when we asked for Snowden...

Comment: @SJuan76 If you're comment was an answer then...answer. Don't put answers in the chat.

Comment: Do you mean to ask 'would Russia extradite to the US?'

Comment: @Lawyer. No, I was asking you to clarify your question because you do not explain what you are refering to. **IF** it is what I think, it seems that you think that the USA government has the ability to extradite people from Russia, which is false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Could the US extradite the Russian Hackers who started the cyber attack against the US private sector and US government agencies and
> departments?*

#### No.

The United States and Russia do not have an extradition treaty. See [Russian Indictment and Extradition | American Constitution Society](https://www.acslaw.org/expertforum/russian-indictment-and-extradition/). And within Russia, extradition is constitutionally prohibited; see [Chapter 2. Rights and Freedoms of Man And Citizen | The Constitution of the Russian Federation](http://www.constitution.ru/en/10003000-03.htm).

> *Is there forced extradition?*

#### Maybe.

Either country could use covert action or even start a war to "force" extradition, or use a form of covert or overt rendition to bring the individuals to a country to face trial.

Comment: Russia **can’t** extradite its own citizens - its constitutionally prohibited.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

The US could file an extradition request for the hackers involved. It would need to know who they were, and have significant evidence that they were responsible and that their actions were a crime under both US and Russian law.

But if the hackers were in fact sponsored or employed by the Russian Government, as has been claimed, I would expect extradition to be refused, probably on some pretext, perhaps that what was done was not illegal under Russian law for some reason.

Extradition is never automatic, the country where the wanted person is can choose to honor a demand or not. The risk is that if a demand is refused, demands the other way may also be refused, and other forms of international pressure may be used. The effectiveness of that will depend on the relationship and relative positions of the countries involved.